# New line character not being printed when setting innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `django` template in which my `javascript` function has the following lines,

```
resDiv = document.getElementById("res");
console.log(result.des);
resDiv.innerHTML+=('<h3 style="padding-bottom:50px;"><strong>Desciption: </strong><br><br><i style="color:#0B45A4;">'+result.des+'</i></h3>');
```

When console.log is executed, it is printed along with new lines in `result.des`.

But when I concatenate it and try try to fill the `innerHTML` of `resDiv` the new lines are not being printed.

All new lines are removed and is filled.

How can I make sure that the new lines are printed in `resDiv`?

Comment: Add the corresponding HTML to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, and be sure that `resDiv` is your real target

```
resDiv.innerHTML = resDiv.innerHTML.concat('<h3 style="padding-bottom:50px;"><strong>Desciption: </strong><br><br><i style="color:#0B45A4;">'+result.des+'</i></h3>');
```

Answer (score 0):

from your question it is not totally clear, what you mean, but I guess that you just need to replace the newlines in `result.des` (e.g. `\n`, `\r`) with html newlines `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

When you concatenate your `result.des`, make sure you put `<br>` tag between lines.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

If `result.des` is a javascript array, you can do `result.des.join('<br>');`